# Scan And Scroll Query In ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 1.5 version, I used the scroll query, id ,I ts working fine and returning the scroll id

> GET /ecommerce_parts/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=3m

```
{
"query": { "match_all": {}},
"size": 1000
}

{
"scrollid": "c2Nhbjs1OzE4Okk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTc6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxNjpJOHJFZEpXdFF3Q1NtdlFNZDVmQVNROzIwOkk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTk6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxO3RvdGFsX2hpdHM6MTg0NjEwOw==",
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
"total": 5,
"successful": 5,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": {
"total": 184610,
"max_score": 0,
"hits": []
}
}
```

Now when I passing the scroll id to retrieve the set of documents its throwing an error

> GET /_search/scroll?scroll=1m 
>   c2Nhbjs1OzE4Okk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTc6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxNjpJOHJFZEpXdFF3Q1NtdlFNZDVmQVNROzIwOkk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTk6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxO3RvdGFsX2hpdHM6MTg0NjEwOw==

```
{
"error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Malformed scrollId []]",
"status": 400
}
```

> GET
>   /_search/scroll?scroll=3mc2Nhbjs1OzIzOkk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MjE6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsyNTpJOHJFZEpXdFF3Q1NtdlFNZDVmQVNROzI0Okk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MjI6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxO3RvdGFsX2hpdHM6MTg0NjEwOw==

Both of the above queries giving me an error how to retrieve the documents based on the scroll id, If m wrong please suggest a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For subsequent requests, you're supposed to send the scroll ID in a JSON payload like this:

```
POST  /_search/scroll 
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "c2Nhbjs1OzE4Okk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTc6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxNjpJOHJFZEpXdFF3Q1NtdlFNZDVmQVNROzIwOkk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTk6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxO3RvdGFsX2hpdHM6MTg0NjEwOw==" 
}
```

In earlier versions of ES you could do it like this, too:

```
POST /_search/scroll?scroll=1m&scroll_id=c2Nhbjs1OzE4Okk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTc6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxNjpJOHJFZEpXdFF3Q1NtdlFNZDVmQVNROzIwOkk4ckVkSld0UXdDU212UU1kNWZBU1E7MTk6SThyRWRKV3RRd0NTbXZRTWQ1ZkFTUTsxO3RvdGFsX2hpdHM6MTg0NjEwOw==
```

Comment: Thanks Val  for your comment ,but its giving me the following error.I am using 1.5 version ES

Comment: {
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Failed to decode scrollId]; nested: IOException[Bad Base64 input character decimal 123 in array position 0]; ",
   "status": 400
}